# CMIS with multiple repositories?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, dms, ecm

I am working on a Java solution which integrates with CMIS repositories. Having chosen OpenCMIS as my open source library, am trying to ensure all test scenarios are covered. I have explored few of the repositories (Alfresco, Chemistry InMemory, Chemistry Fileshare, OpenKM) and none of them seem to provide multiple repositories which I feel is required to be covered as a part of my testing.

Being more specific with the code, below works well with almost all repositories.

Repository soleRepository = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0);

But I want to know if any repository supports (or can be configured to support) this code:
**sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter).get(*1*)**

Comment: IIRC the Alfresco Cloud has one repo per network, so if you've got a developer key you could always try that for an Alfresco multi-repo setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many CMIS servers supporting more than one repository. SharePoint, FileNet, SAP Mobile Documents, ...

Even the OpenCMIS FileShare server supports more than one repository if you configure it. Just add the following lines to your `repository.properties` file and it will expose second repository:

```
repository.second = {user.home}
repository.second.readwrite = test, cmisuser
repository.second.readonly = reader
```